# Compact embedding of Banach spaces; when does a bounded sequence converge in the bigger space?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces with $X$ compactly embedded in $Y$.

What more assumptions do I need on the spaces to ensure that: every sequence $x_n \in X$ which is bounded ($\lVert x_n \rVert_X < C$) is such that $x_n \to y$ in $Y$ for some $y \in Y$?

Note that the full sequence should converge, not just a subsequence.

Comment: You need $X=\{0\}$.

Comment: I give you some explanation on David's comment. If $v \in X$ is non zero, then $(-1)^nv$ is bounded. But this obviously cannot be convergent.

Comment: In many cases. you can obtain convergence with additional properties on your sequence, e.g. weak convergence of the sequence, pointwise convergence (in $L^p$ spaces). More generally, the following holds: If there is $y\in Y$ such that every subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence with limit $y$, the whole sequence converges towards $y$. This can be used if you know that the limit satisfies a (uniquely solvable) equation.